# This.id passed using ajax to php but returns an undefined index when load by jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been searching around the Internet and even in Website Development forums but luckily I Haven't found a solution to my problem.

**This is the html code**

```
<div id='bottom-right-display'>
                    <ul id='display-app'>
                        <li><a href='#' class='btn-test-1' id='123'>Testing1</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#' class='btn-test-2'>Testing2</a></li>
                        <li><a href='#' class='btn-test-3'>Testing3</a></li>
                    </ul>
</div>
```

**This is the jquery code**

```
$(".btn-test-1").click(function(){
        //with the use of post
        $.post("somefile.php",{id,this.id},function(data){
            $("#outputarea").load("somefile.php");
        });
        //or
        //with the use of ajax
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "somefile.php",  
            data: {id:this.id},      
            success: function(result){  
              $("#outputarea").load("somefile.php");
            } 
        })
    });
```

**This is the php code**

```
<?php
     require_once "connection.php";

     $sorter = $_POST["id"];//------>THIS IS THE LINE OF CODE WHERE THE ERROR IS STATING ABOUT!!
     $retrieve = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `id` != '$sorter'");
     $retrieve->execute();
     $retrieve->bind_result($groupname);

     while($retrieve->fetch()){
        echo "<li>".$groupname."</li>";
     }
?>
```

The problem is passing a this.id using $.post or $.ajax to php but returns an error saying **Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\somefile.php** when using load but when using alert it display the result that I wanted, I even tried using isset but it is empty and no data at all. Please if you know any already answered question or solution for this please comment it T_T.

Comment: Check to see if the data is actually in the post request. IE: `if(isset($_POST['id'])) $sorter = $_POST['id']; else die('ERROR: No ID set')`

Comment: Replace `{id,this.id}` with `{id: this.id}`?

Comment: I also notice that you only have an `id=""` on the first `<li>` the other 2 `<li>`'s dont have an `id=""` to pass to the PHP script

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer I've tried it but sadly the error is the one that displayed.

Comment: @TobiasXy I already did that but still it is in undefined.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yeah because at the jquery script I only called the btn-test-1 for the ID

Comment: @Middle-Level send us the result that you see when you paste this code at the top of your file: `echo "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>"; die();`

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer where i will paste that?? in the php code?? or at the url?? because if it is pasted in php code the result is array{}

Comment: That means the id is not passed to the webserver / php. Maybe try if it works with a GET request?

Comment: @TobiasXy I changed $_POST to $_GET still it display array{}

Comment: Of course you also have to change the javascript to make a GET request instead of a POST request.

Comment: @TobiasXy this is what I got Array
(
    [_] => 1454335202743
)

Comment: @TobiasXy try to see what is in `$_REQUEST`, usually all `$_GET` and `$_POST` parameters are combined in `$_REQUEST`. If any of these return `array{}` then that means that your Javascript isn't posting the data to the server. So that is where the issue lies. See my answer below on how to use a `DataForm` to post the data back.

Comment: `$(".btn-test-1").click(function(){
        var id_val = $(this).attr('id');
        //with the use of ajax
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "somefile.php",  
            data: {id:id_val },      
            success: function(result){  
              $("#outputarea").load("somefile.php");
            } 
        })
    });`


check this:

1. is URL is correct?
2. print $_POST array if id is really pass from JS?
3. load only return result in div like $("#outputarea").append(result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the data is actually in the post request.

i.e.

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) $sorter = $_POST['id']; 
else die('ERROR: No ID set')
```

Then I would also check if you can send data to the server via AJAX that way. Otherwise try adding this code to your Javascript.

```
$(".btn-test-1").click(function(){

    var $dta = new FormData();

    $dta.append("id",this.id);

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "somefile.php",  
        data: $dta,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(result){  
          $("#outputarea").html(result);
        } 
    })
});
```

Comment: Hope you dont mind `IE:` looked like you were talking and Internet Explorer

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks :) I actually didn't realize that

Comment: I've done the isset but sadly it is the error that prevailed. I tried your code but still it has the same result. I don't know if it is really the passing is the problem because when I remove the $("#outputarea").load("somefile.php"); but change it to alert(result) the result I wanted displayed but when I used the load the undefined index error is the one displaying

Comment: @Middle-Level - Sorry I actually made a mistake there, it wasn't supposed to be `.load` it should have been `.html`. The load command actually does a simplified `GET` request of the page.

Comment: This one literally work!. To all who help me out with this I actually thank you all because my 3 days of researching is now done and it is because all of you guys. Appreciated all your answers.

Comment: @Middle-Level if you ever get stuck and don't want to ask on StackExchange you can always send me an email :) always happy to help. My email can be found on http://jacqueskoekemoer.co.za

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer Noted :D looking forward to it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you first send an ajax request with the `id` attached, but in the success callback you request `somefile.php` again. The second time no id is attached.

Instead you should use the result variable to get the "output" of somefile.php from the first request. The second request is not needed.

Like this:

```
$(".btn-test-1").click(function(){
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "somefile.php",  
        data: {id:this.id},      
        success: function(result){  
          $("#outputarea").html(result);
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Still the same error undefined index using the html(result) but the thing is when I do this <?php $sorter = $_POST['id']; echo $sorter; ?> and in the jquery do the alert(result) it displays that it has a data passed on it but when I used either .load or .html it still has the undefined index error.

Comment: That's strange. Then show us the content of the `$_POST` variable as Jacques suggested in his comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your codes seem okay. One thing that I cannot simulate though is your `required 'connection.php'`. Can you simplify your php code first? I mean just do echo `$_POST['id']` just to make sure your preceding code(s) is not affecting your post data.

Comment: the required connection.php doesn't have any problem at all the only thing that is the problem is the passing of the id value of a clicked element using ajax or post but It literally become empty

Answer (score 0):

change jquery to this and try :

```
$(".btn-test-1").click(function(){
        var id_val = $(this).attr('id');
        //with the use of ajax
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "somefile.php",  
            data: {id:id_val },      
            success: function(result){  
              $("#outputarea").load("somefile.php");
            } 
        })
    });
```